# Get all business units

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to retrieve all business units from CRM 2013.

Tried the following query

```
        var query = _serviceContext.BusinessUnitSet
                            .Where(b => b.EntityState == 0)
                            .Select(x => new
                                        {
                                            Name = x.Name,
                                            Id = x.Id
                                        }
                                    )
                            .ToList();
```

Using this query I am receiving an error just stating:

```
{System.ServiceModel.FaultCode} {attributeName} {System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<System.ServiceModel.FaultReasonText>}
```

When googling on the subject I found information about how to retrieve single business units (which seems to be different from retrieving a "normal" entity), but not how to get them all ([link](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11d6693e-b963-4cbb-b8a3-35628a959f93/how-to-get-current-user-business-unit-details-in-crm-2011-using-c-plugin?forum=crmdevelopment)).

Any help as to how I would retrieve all business units would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're not getting any sort of error information?  I'm assuming this is CRM Online?  Is this within a plugin context, or is this an app accessing the SDK outside of CRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to get all active business units from system. So you must use `IsDisabled` property to get them. The property you use [EntityState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitystate.aspx) is used for tracking the entity state in context, not to indicate state of entity in CRM. See [BusinessUnit Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309617.aspx) for more info about BU entity.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using QueryExpression

```
    public class BusinessUnit
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }


    public void GetAllBusinessUnits(Action<QueryExpression> queryModifier = null)
    {

        foreach (BusinessUnit m in RetrieveAllBusinessUnit(this.Service, 1000, queryModifier))
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable<BusinessUnit> RetrieveAllBusinessUnit(IOrganizationService service, int count = 1000, Action<QueryExpression> queryModifier = null)
    {

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("businessunit")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("businessunitid", "name"),

            PageInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                Count = count,
                PageNumber = 1,
                PagingCookie = null,
            }
        };

        if (queryModifier != null)
        {
            queryModifier(query);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            foreach (Entity e in results.Entities)
            {
                yield return new BusinessUnit()
                {
                    Id = e.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("businessunitid"),
                    Name = e.GetAttributeValue<String>("name")
                };
            }

            if (results.MoreRecords)
            {
                query.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
                query.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
```